# Why do I get an error when connecting to a tftp server PXE-T00 pxelinux.0 filename too long?

Tags: pxe-boot, dnsmasq, mikrotik

As a DHCP server, I have a Mikrotik configured with options 66 and 67.

```
/ip dhcp-server option
add name="option66" code=66 value="s'10.10.14.200'"
add name="option67" code=67 value="'pxelinux.0'"
/ip dhcp-server option sets
add name="set-pxe" options=option66,option67
```

The TFTP server is dnsmasq

```
port=0
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,servername,10.10.14.200
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/tftp
tftp-no-fail
```

When trying to connect as a client, in the server logs

```
pxe dnsmasq-tftp[34708]: cannot read /var/tftp/pxelinux.0: File name too long
```

If you log in with a tftp client from a remote host, you can download any file, including pxelinux.0

Comment: Try to compare with `tcpdump` TFTP traffic when you are trying to boot with PXE and when you are connecting with a normal TFTP client. I suspect that the filename is transferred differently.

Comment: I notice that you have s' for option66 but no s for 67 in your dhcp config. you should probably avoid to configure the same options in both dnsmasq and dhcp, you can usually do without dnsmasq when you are in control of main dhcp, which can simplify your setup.